# CorePlot XAxis Labels not displaying

Tags: core-plot, label

Hey,
Using CorePlot recently but the Problem is, that the Labels I set don´t show up, the one thing I can see are the major and minor TickLine, but also only above the x-line not below.

Here is my code:

```
subViewGraph=[[CPGraphHostingView alloc]init];

subViewGraph.frame=CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 280);
    subViewGraph.bounds=CGRectMake(0, 40, 320,280);
[self.view addSubview:subViewGraph];

graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:subViewGraph.bounds];

CPTheme *theme = [CPTheme themeNamed:kCPPlainWhiteTheme];
[graph applyTheme:theme];
subViewGraph.hostedGraph=graph;
graph.paddingBottom=40;

// Define some custom labels for the data elements  
CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPXYAxis *x=axisSet.xAxis;

CPLineStyle *lineStyle = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor redColor];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
x.majorIntervalLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2"]decimalValue];
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 4;
x.majorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
x.minorTickLineStyle = lineStyle;
x.axisLineStyle = lineStyle;
x.minorTickLength = 5.0f;
x.majorTickLength = 10.0f;
x.labelOffset=3.0;
x.labelRotation = M_PI/4;
x.labelTextStyle.color=[CPColor blueColor];

NSArray *customTickLocations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:0], 
                                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:2], 
                                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:4], 
                                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:6], 
                                nil];
NSArray *xAxisLabels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Label A", @"Label B", @"Label C", @"Label D", nil];
NSUInteger labelLocation = 0;
NSMutableArray *customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[xAxisLabels count]];
for (NSNumber *tickLocation in customTickLocations) {
    CPAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: [xAxisLabels objectAtIndex:labelLocation++] textStyle:axisSet.xAxis.labelTextStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
    [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
    [newLabel release];
}

axisSet.xAxis.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];
axisSet.xAxis.title=@"Hello";

// Define the space for the bars.
CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(150.0f)];
plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(12.0f)];


//  Bar plot
CPBarPlot *barPlot = [CPBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPColor yellowColor] horizontalBars:NO];
barPlot.dataSource = self;
barPlot.baseValue = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
barPlot.barOffset = 1.0f;
barPlot.barWidth = 20.0f;
barPlot.identifier = @"BlueBarPlot";

[graph addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found it out myself. You have to add some different padding:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom=40;
```

Now my xaxis is visible.

Comment: Thanks for posting your own answer! I was having the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

... or simply do:

```
barChartView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
barChartView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```