# How to display bar base value of barplot in coreplot iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5, core-plot

I am able to show the bar plots tip value. But I dont have any idea of how to display the bar's base value at bar's base end in coreplot.

Can anyone suggest me how can show the bar's base value.

Comment: may be this link will be help full http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110913/x-axis-labels-in-coreplot-not-displayed?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, but this is not useful for me. I need to display  bar base value on the graph